# create a select dropdown from database in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

#### I am new with codeigniter.I want to make a select dorpdown that gets its value and title from database.I tried some codes but it did not work.There are my codes:

*Model*

```
function get_sec_info(){
$records=$this->db->query('SELECT sec_id,name FROM section');
if($records->num_rows() > 0)
return $records->result();}
```

*Controller*

```
  function sec_ifo(){
$data['rec']=$this->mymodel->get_sec_info();
$this->load->view('article',$data);}
```

*View*

```
 <select name="section">
<?php foreach($rec as $row) {?>
<option value="<?php echo $row->sec_id?>"><?php echo $row->name ?></option>"
<?php } ?>
```

*It does not show any error and any option to show*

Comment: possible duplicate of [making a select dropdown from database in codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22020438/making-a-select-dropdown-from-database-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 1):

In the controller you set "red" `$data['red']` and in the view you access "rec" `foreach($rec`

Answer (score 0):

**Model:**

```
function get_sec_info(){

$this->db->select('sec_id,name');

$records = $this->db->get('section');

return $records->result();

}
```

**Controller:**

```
function sec_ifo(){

$this->load->model('mymodel');

$this->data['red'] = $this->mymodel->get_sec_info();

$this->load->view('article',$this->data);

}
```

**View:**

```
<select name="section">
<?php foreach($red as $row) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row->sec_id; ?>"><?php echo $row->name; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Model*

```
public function getClasse() {
    $query(`enter code here`);       
    $result = $this->db->query($query)->result_array();

    foreach ($result as $key => $rows) {
        $resultado[] = $rows['DescricaoClasse'];
    }
    return $resultado;
}
```

*Controller:*

```
public function getClasse() {
    $this->load->model('Decisao_monocratica_model');
    return $this->Decisao_monocratica_model->getClasse();
}
```

*View*

```
<select id="ClasseProcesso" class="input-xlarge" name="classeProcesso">
    <option value="0">Todos os Tipos</option>
        <? foreach ($classeProcesso as $key => $classe) { ?>
            <option value="<? echo $classe ?>"><? echo $classe ?></option>
        <? } ?>
</select>
```